# Deleted a question with no answer and banned

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, post-ban

I deleted a question because it was marked as a duplicate, so I deleted it. There was no comment-answers, just my question there, probably a moderator marked as a duplicate because it was so fast between I ask that question and marked as a duplicate. After then I see this magical line;

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Isn't it unfair? What can I do, I didn't know it was a duplicate,so when It marked, I learned it and deleted it. And I banned, I don't think it's a good system. Because there was no answers and even no comments, I saw it is a duplicate and I deleted my question. I think filter of system is has to ignore this, if a question without any answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off we [don't usually delete duplicates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) because they act as "signposts" for future readers searching for the same thing. I undeleted your duplicate question.

The question ban itself is because of the sum of your contributions, not any single question, so no I don't think the situation you described is unfair.

Furthermore deleting questions is a bad thing to do when you're question-banned (or nearly banned). Instead read the advice given at the link you see when you are blocked [or this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: I get down-votes because it was a duplicate, so I deleted it. Should I wait till its -20 instead of deleting it?

Comment: @qqvc normally the votes stop happening pretty quickly after getting closed as duplicates. Bringing things to meta does tend to distort voting somewhat though. I've temporarily locked it whilst discussing the question here.

Comment: @qqvc if you want I'll undelete some of the other questions so that you can fix those and work to lift the ban.

Comment: I can do if it take the ban back, I thought if I delete the question it will be good for clearity. No duplicates is better I thought.

Comment: @qqvc It probably wont fix the ban itself - you'll still need to edit them to fix whatever problems caused them to be closed/deleted in the first place.

Comment: Some of them I deleted because some of my "fans" down-voting my questions,thats why. I really don't know what to do for "edit", I think they are already edited or I edit them what I want to ask.. But I'll try to edit them as you suggested, hope no more down-votes

Comment: @qqvc go into the chat room corresponding to the question's language, get to know the people there and then (after you know the norms of the room), ask about how to improve specific questions if that is acceptable for the room's community.